# Number of connected subgraphs of the complete unlabelled graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an explicit formula for the number of connected graphs with at most $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've misunderstood you, just just want to know how many distinct connected graphs there are on $n$ vertices. There is nothing simple known. [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001349) gives values for up to $K_{20}$ and some links to references.

Comment: It could be that OP wants the number of distinct connected graphs on *at most* $n$ vertices. Of course, your answer is still apropos.

Comment: Is there an explict formula for the number of connected graphs with at most $n$ vertics?